# Getting this below error while running puppet agent -t?

Tags: puppet

I am getting this error every time I ran puppet agent -t on the agent.

```
Error: Facter: error while resolving custom facts in /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/lib/facter/ipaddresses.rb: cannot load such file -- facter/util/ip
```

Can anyone help me in resolving this error?

I have tried various solutions but nothing seems to be working. Like installing gems package etc.
Puppet version I am ones 5.5.2

Comment: It might be related to the version of facter https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/FACT-1400 it would be useful to see the ipaddresses.rb file.

Comment: Your Puppet installation appears to be broken.  Has it ever worked correctly?  Facter is bundled together with Puppet in all the official Puppet 5 distribution kits, and it should work correctly out of the box.  Do note, however, that Puppet 5 is obsolete, and nearing the end of its support window.  You should consider upgrading to Puppet 7.  If you don't want to upgrade then you should probably at least obtain and install a clean Puppet 5 distribution.  This is easier if your site has never worked than if it has existing certs and nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling/storing the file from the correct directory?

Error: Facter: error while resolving custom facts in /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/lib/facter/ipaddresses.rb:

The file ipaddresses.rb seems to be in folder 'facter', however, in the error you have a path facter/util/ip.

'Util' folder is within the 'Facter' folder, so you might have an incorrect path hence why the agent run is failing.